# What are PayPal CallBack parameters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, paypal, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a PayPal callback method in my ASp.NET MVC controller called: PayPalCallBack(FormCollection form)

The problem is I cannot get any values(e.g. cm(custom), st(payment_status) etc.) from this form variable.

But when the method is finished, I did see the return url came with those values

```
https://www.mywebsite.net/Event/PayPalCallBack?tx=4KT34448LJ0584918&st=Completed&amt=0%2e11&cc=AUD&cm=3%2f23%2f2014%2011%3a00%3a00%20AM%7c3%2f23%2f2014%2012%3a00%3a00%20PM%7cWinTech%7cmr%7cWinston%7cFan%7cfranva008%40gmail%2ecom%7c0425620666%7c1&item_number=
```

So, I guess, I am using a wrong type of variable to receive its return values.

My questions are:

1. what should be the right type of parameter used in my PayPalCallBack( values)?
2. what parameters can the return_url have?

Note: I am asking the return values/parameters in return_url, not the notify_url which is used in PayPal IPN.

### Update 1

I think, QueryString should be the right type to use in this case.
But I tried to use it and found it's not the ASP.NET WebForm Response.QueryString instead, it is
Microsoft.Owin.QueryString.

Do I need to add some references in order to use the Response.QueryString?

### Update 2

I have found the right QueryString.

Comment: The return_url can have any parameters you like. You don't state what any of your difficulties are beyond 'cannot get any values'. Your difficulties seem to consist of lack of API knowledge rather than anything to do specifically with PayPal.

Comment: @EJP, hi thx for your opinion. Do you have actual code for stating your opinion?